# NSDictionary custom object store and retrieve

Tags: ios, objective-c

Trying to store value in NSDictionary and retrieve it

Objects

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@class ATTTEstOBJ;

@interface ATTTEst : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *string1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *string2;
@property (nonatomic, retain) ATTTEstOBJ *obj1;

@end


@interface ATTTEstOBJ : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *string3;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *string4;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *array1;

@end
```

I know it needs to be encoded properly to save and retrieve values.but In this case it is  a  composite object and I have no idea, how to deal it with.

```
- (void) encodeWithCoder: (NSCoder *)coder
```

So TLDR , How to save the composite value into dictionary and retrieve it back

I want to store `ATTTest` into a dictionary and retrieve it back.

EDIT : Detailed explanation

```
ATTTEst *test=[[ATTTEst alloc]init];
test.string1=@"a";
test.string2=@"b";


ATTTEstOBJ *obj=[[ATTTEstOBJ alloc]init];
obj.string3=@"c";
obj.string4=@"d";

test.obj1=obj;



NSMutableDictionary *dict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithCapacity:3];

[dict setObject:test forKey:@"test"];
NSLog(@"%@",dict);

ATTTEst *tester=[dict objectForKey:test];
NSLog(@"%@",tester.obj1.string3);
```

IT shows null.as output I want to get the value  as c for `tester.obj1.string3`

Comment: How does it related to NSDictionary? Are you trying to save it to a file?

Comment: encode String1, string2, string3, string4, array1 in the encoder method and decode it with the same keys you encoded them with.

Comment: I don't understand it either. How is storing into a dictionary (`[dict setObject:myATTTestObject forKey:key]` related to encoding?

Comment: @MartinR did it get null as response

Comment: @LithuT.V: Please show the code how to store and retrieve the object, and where exactly it fails. A [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) would be optimal. I guess that we don't understand yet what you are actually trying to achieve.

Comment: `ATTTEst *tester=[dict objectForKey:test];` this is wrong. Do `ATTTEst *tester=[dict objectForKey:@"test"];`.

Comment: Sorry it is a typo in question.

Comment: @LithuT.V: But without that typo, everything works as expected, I just tested it.

Comment: @MartinR Yup its good,But the same way doesnt work with map graphic attributes :O is there some problem in that? I am trying out map callout graphic attributes

Comment: @LithuT.V: Sorry, but I have no experience with maps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ATTTEst *tester=[dict objectForKey:test];
```

should be

```
ATTTEst *tester=[dict objectForKey:@"test"];
```

You have used the object `test` (instead of the string `@"test"`) as key when retrieving the object. I don't think that
was intentionally.

Answer (score -1):

In order to store them into NSDictionary, you don't need to encode them.

Just do:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:, attestObject,@"attestObject", attest2Object,@"atttest2" nil];
```

Where attestObject and attest2Object are the objects you want to store, and strings are their keys.

This has nothing to do with encoding...